# Apply absolute contrast and brightness using Imagemagick

Tags: php, css, graphics, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a tool which allows to justify contrast and brightness of image online using CSS3 filters. Thus I got two values of brightness and contrast from 0 to [inf] which means "1" is no change in brightness/contrast.

Next step, I need to apply these changes to image physically using Imagemagick. I've digged a ton of docs but not found how I can apply these 2 values to image.

It is relatively simple way to apply brightness and contrast corrections to image file using command-line Imagemagick?

Comment: You already read this? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#brightness-contrast

Comment: @Ruud yes, but -brightness-contrast option is unavailable in my version. I have not chance to reinstall it.

Comment: I have no idea what options ARE available in your version, but here are some suggestions: -contrast, -contrast-stretch, -modulate, -sigmoidal-contrast, -watermark. Just wondering: what IS keeping you from upgrading?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by using for example:

```
convert -brightness-contrast 10X10 1.png 2.png
```